# Does the curve $f(x,y)=x^4-y^2x^2+9y^2=0$ pass through origin?

Tags: graphing-functions, curves, plane-curves

When we put $x=0$ in $f(x,y)$ we get $y=0$ $\implies$ f(x,y) passess through the origin. But Wolfram says that it doesn't. So, what is the mess?

Wolfram link- https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-y%5E2x%5E2%2B9y%5E2%3D0

Comment: Ask for a plot of $x^4-y^2 x^2+9y^2=0.01$

Comment: It does not **_pass_** through the origin. The origin is just a single isolated point

Comment: Of course it does. What is going wrong is that the curve has an isolated real point at $(0,0)$. Moral: don't trust pictures like this more than your brain!

Comment: f(0,0)= 0 then it passes through the origin !!

Comment: Seems that blind trust in Wolfram can be dangerous.

Comment: The origin is an isolated point of the graph.

Comment: Is there a convention what "passes through" shoud mean ? If not, the discussion is quite obsolete. The claim "the origin lies on the graph" is surely true, but "passes through" might require that the function is continous or even differentiable.

Comment: @Neferititi & Emilio but still (0,0) is not depicted on the graph by Wolfram

Comment: Probably, the origin is not visible becuase of the displayed axis.

Comment: @Peter are you sure about this?

Comment: @ankit: I am not sure what you want anyone to say. Either this point is depicted, but hard to see because of the axes, or not depicted, in which case Wolfram Alpha is messing up. Either way, it doesn't change the fact that $(0,0)$ is in the solution set.

Comment: I tried $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2$. Wolfram did not chose the right ranges to display the point. Then, I tried $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=0$ and did not see the point $(1/1)$. Wolfram might have problems with such graphs. At least the solution is always displayed.

Comment: Ironically (given how often the reverse migration happens), this is probably better for the Mathematica StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=0,y=0$ is satisfied. So *contains* the  origin for sure. To *pass* through it, derivative continuity in its neighborhood is required, which it fails as an isolated "island" point, because it also confirms by

EDIT1:

plotting $ y=f(x) = \dfrac{x^2} {\sqrt{(x-3)(x+3)}}, y$ is seen undefined in open interval $0<x < 3$ and $0>x > -3 $ due to imaginary $y.$

Hoever in a 3 D Contour plot,the origin in fact does appear as a small peak around the surrounding/submerging waters... with RHS set to a very small quantity instead of 0.It shows that it passes through the origin and has zero partial derivatives there.

[image: Origin= the isolated peak point]

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this definition of pass through?